# my sculpting tool is kind a hard to use, anybody knows how to change?

Tags: sculpting

So, I am new to blender, actually to 3d softwares and started learning on blender, I was watching a "blender guru" video, was working on modeling mode, object mode etc and when reaches sculpting, in the video he does like the easiest thing on earth, but in my pc I need to use the stylus like 30x in the same area to make a bit diferrence.

Didn't found any solution online.
Anyone know how to help?

(Sorry bad english)

Comment: try increasing the **strength** of the brush.

Comment: already did, not work

Comment: man... i cant believe... it was THE SIZE OF THE BRUSH... man im so dumb

Comment: your not dumb, you're just a beginner. :)  even experts make mistakes like that every now and then. :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question. Are you looking for better affordable options than stylus? I recommend you the wacom intuos pen & touch art. But unless you just want to sculpt in blender or to digital painting you will rarely need it I guess. I have the small model and I can't complain.

watch these:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW79bRD6aj0&t=57s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fEFbzKz8-g

Comment: hey man, sorry, now i saw my question didn't have much coherence
im already know about stylus and art and general, im only new on 3d
but in the video, the guy was sculpting so easy, and in my software wasnt, i saw modifiers not applyed could affect the sculpting mod, but already have applyed, already increased the strenght of brush, but the sculpting keeps hard for some reason

btw: others objects are not this hard, they are normal

Comment: hey man, thanks for trying to help ^^
already solved, was just the size of the brush, it seems a bit bugged for me, or its just a blender thing that i need to be used to

anyway, really thanks

Comment: Good thing you solved it.